# Integer factorization given modular square root of 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms

Let $N$ be composite. It is well-known that if $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod N$, and $x \neq \pm 1 \pmod N$, then a factor of $N$ is easily found by computing gcd($N$, $x + 1$). I'm curious if there is a similar approach to factor $N$ given $y$ such that $y^2 \equiv 2 \pmod N$. (We are obviously assuming that 2 is a quadratic residue mod $N$).

Comment: It works if you have two such $y$ which don't sum to $0$.

Comment: For a bit more analysis in the case where N is an RSA modulus, see Section 4 of Rabin's ["Digitalized Signatures and Public Key Functions as Intractable as Factorization"](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a078415.pdf) .